LinearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition not working with PagingDataAdapter
I am trying to learn paging library 3.0 but i cannot set totalItemCount for PagingDataAdapter.
getItemCount returns only the loaded items size thus scrollToPosition not working beyond loaded items.
MyViewModel.java
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int PREFACE_DISTANCE = 3;
    private static final boolean PLACEHOLDER = true;

    LiveData<PagingData<User>> getData() {
        PagingConfig config = new PagingConfig(PAGE_SIZE, PREFACE_DISTANCE, PLACEHOLDER);
        Pager<Integer, User> pager = new Pager<>(config, MyDataSource::new);
        return PagingLiveData.cachedIn(PagingLiveData.getLiveData(pager), this);
    }
}

MyDataSource.java
public class MyDataSource extends PagingSource<Integer, User> {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Integer getRefreshKey(@NonNull PagingState<Integer, User> state) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object load(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> loadParams, @NonNull Continuation<? super LoadResult<Integer, User>> continuation) {
        Integer key = loadParams.getKey();
        if (key == null) key = 0;
        int size = loadParams.getLoadSize();
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < loadParams.getLoadSize(); i++) {
            int id = key + i;
            list.add(new User(id, "position: " + id));
        }
        return new LoadResult.Page<>(list, key > 0 ? key - 10 : null, key + size);
    }
}

